# Override value of @PreAuthorize using @AliasFor

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following combined custom annotation with Springs @PreAuthorize annotation,

```
@RequestMapping(
        produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE + ";charset=UTF-8",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('permitAll()')")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Get {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = PreAuthorize.class, attribute = "value")
    String authorize() default "permitAll()";
}
```

And I've got the following client using it

```
@Get(value = "/users", authorize = "hasRole('ROLE_GET_USERS')")
public List<User> retrieveUsers() {
   // body
}
```

As you can see the purpose is to allow clients of `@Get` annotation to override the `@PreAuthorize` so that they can provide the role they require for.

I din't have so far any problem using `@AliasFor`, even in this example `@RequestMapping` is working, but unfortunately it does not override the value of `@PreAuthorize` and everyone can still access the resources as the default value is `permitAll()`.

I wonder first of all why this does not work, and second if it is possible to make it work?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this old question, but the "Spring Annotation Programming Model" says that AliasFor can't be used for stereotype annotations such as Component and "The reason is that the special handling of these value attributes was in place years before AliasFor was invented. Consequently, due to backward compatibility issues it is simply not possible to use AliasFor with such value attributes." It's possible that PreAuthorize and PostAuthorize also have special handling...perhaps to handle the Spring Expression Language. More generally, AliasFor doesn't always work.